# non analytic functions

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Find two functions, each of which is nowhere analytic, but whose sum is an entire function.

I can give examples of functions that are analytic nowhere, but can't find two that add to an entire function.

Comment: If you have one function $f(z)$ which is nowhere analytic, then you can take the other function as $-f(z)$, and then adding them together you get $0$.

Answer (score 6):

$f_1(z) = \operatorname{re} z$, $f_2(z) = i\operatorname{im} z$.

Then $f_1(z)+f_2(z) = z$.

Answer (score 0):

Silly example: let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ be nowhere analytic. Then if $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ is analytic, $g(z)-f(z)$ is also nowhere analytic. But
$$ f(z) + (g(z)-f(z)) = g(z), $$
which is analytic.